# Native code interop in a weex app

Tags: javascript, interop, native, weex

i'm new to Weex framework and i'm wondering if there's a way to inject native code directly in the app. Or perhaps some sort of interoperability between js and native code?
I'm trying to add some cookie-based auth logic and animated transitions between views and it seems there's no way to achieve this in Weex without native code.

Answer (score 0):

First, There is NO way to inject native code via js-bundle.

Second, The feature of animated transitions, you can try with [BindingX](https://github.com/alibaba/bindingx). Timing Event is suitable for you. Translate your transition into an expression.
The expression is the interoperability between native and js.